# How many pets are there in Mists and is there a limit?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In [this first-hand account](http://wow.joystiq.com/2012/08/03/my-first-day-with-mists-of-pandarias-pet-battles/) of getting started with Pet Battles in Mists of Pandaria, he captures plenty of new pets in just the Stormwind/Elwynn Forest area:

- Stormwind Rat
- Fawn
- Squirrel
- Small Frog
- Black Lamb

That seems a huge number.  Is there a limit on pets in Mists?  How many pets are there now in total? Pre-Mists I believe the number was around 180-200.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of pets has indeed exploded with Mists of Pandaria and the introduction of pet battles. There is still a limit because there is still a finite list of pets added to the game, ie. there is no dynamic generation of pets, all the new ones are in-game as critters/etc. I can't find a number easily in game despite the new interface which lists all pets including the ones you don't have yet, however [Wowhead has the number pegged at 662](http://mop.wowhead.com/petspecies) and there are achievements all the way to [400 pets collected](http://mop.wowhead.com/achievement=7501) currently in game.

Comment: You're forgetting, however, that Pets != Battle pets. I.e., Kites aren't battle pets.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: I was hoping there'd be a number in the ingame interface, but sadly not. That listing seems to include non-battle pets also however, for instance Argent Gruntling isn't available for pet battles but is near the top of that list so I believe it's a pretty accurate number. Either way, it's a decent minimum number as almost all pets can be used as battle pets.

Comment: I was actually interested in pets, not battle pets (the "battle" was not edited in by me), though obviously the majority of new pets will be battle pets.

Comment: @dlanod: I wouldn't take take it as a given, but the 662 number seems to be a pretty good starting point. That's a minimum, and there seems to be many non-battle pets in that list so it may well be an accurate count of all companion pets as of right now.

Comment: Now you can have up to 1000 pets

Answer (score 3):

As Matthew says, 662 pets is most likely correct for the total number of pets in Mists of Pandaria.

However it looks like there is a limit on the number of pets - specifically you will be limited to 500, as captured on the beta, so you can no longer capture every pet in the game.

[image]

Comment: 500 is still a lot of pets!

Answer (score 2):

you can have up to a 1000 pets, which I found out by not being able to capture any more! So I sadly had to let a few go in order to go for diversity